# Retorno Datetime Json /Date(1519339100637)/

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net

Boa noite, estou trabalhando com `Ajax` para retornar um `json` que contém um dado no formato `Datetime` mas estou recebendo no formato string `/Date(1519339100637)/`. Como posso converter para o formato data e hora 23/02/2018 12:00:00:

Função Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetData(andamento_id) {
        var $tbl = $('#tbl');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Andamento.aspx/GetComentarioAndamento',
            data: "{'AndamentoID':'" + andamento_id + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + data.d[i].ComentarioTexto
                            + '</td><td>' + data.d[i].DataHoraComentario
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + "<div class='row centered'><div class='user-block'><img src='"
                            + data.d[i].FotoProfile + "' data-toggle='tooltip' title='"
                            + data.d[i].NomeAdvogado + "' class='img-circle img-bordered-sm'></div></div>"
                            + '</td></tr>');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É sempre meio dia, 12:00:00?

Comment: @dvd não é um exemplo 00:00:00

Comment: Entendi... o dia e o horário estão no número.

Comment: E como está o C# que envia o JSON?

Comment: @dvd Funcionou perfeitamente obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um objeto `new Date()` apenas com a parte numérica da expressão, e use `toLocaleString()` para retornar a data no formato `dd-mm-aaaa hh:mm:ss`. Veja como ficaria o `for`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
   var d = new Date(Number(data.d[i].DataHoraComentario.match(/(\d)+/)[0])).toLocaleString();
   $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + data.d[i].ComentarioTexto
       + '</td><td>' + d
       + '</td><td>'
       + "<div class='row centered'><div class='user-block'><img src='"
       + data.d[i].FotoProfile + "' data-toggle='tooltip' title='"
       + data.d[i].NomeAdvogado + "' class='img-circle img-bordered-sm'></div></div>"
       + '</td></tr>');
}
```